# how to add all numbers of a string to array in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, random

So i've been trying to get all the numbers from a string and putting them to an array but i fail :(

**String:** "there's 10 Apples, 8 Grapes, 120 Oranges, and 6363 Lemons."

**desired outcome:**

```
Fruits[0]=10
Fruits[1]=8
Fruits[2]=120
Fruits[3]=6363
```

please help me :) and thank you in advance~

Comment: You have to show what you have tried so far. Anyway, Regular expression could be your starting point or LINQ

Comment: loop each char and use char.isChar()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the sentence into words. Then, check each word to see if it can be converted to an integer; if it can, add it to the list:

```
       string sentence = "there's 10 Apples, 8 Grapes, 120 Oranges, and 6363 Lemons.";
       string[] words = sentence.Split(' ');
       List<int> fruits = new List<int>();
       for (int index = 0; index < words.Count(); index++)
       {
            int number;
            if (int.TryParse(words[index], out number))
            {
                fruits.Add(number);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var sentence = "there's 10 Apples, 8 Grapes, 120 Oranges, and 6363 Lemons.";
Regex rgx = new Regex("\d+");
foreach (Match match in rgx.Matches(sentence))
     Console.WriteLine("Found '{0}'", match.Value);
```